# Button with selector not working in fragment

Tags: android, xamarin.android, fragment

Button selector is not working when applied in `Fragment`. It's working in an `AppCompatDialogFragment` but not in a regular `Fragment` that's instantiated via `FragmentTransaction`. Here's my instantiation code:

```cs
    var transaction = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    var grpFragment = new GroupsFragment();

    transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_frame, grpFragment, GroupsFragment.Tag);
    transaction.Commit();
```

`GroupsFragment.OnViewCreated`:

```cs
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_groups, container, false)!;
    Initialize(view);

    return view;
}
```

In the `fragment_groups.xml` layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/platin_white">

    ...

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
        android:text="Cancel"/>

    ...

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In the `selector_button.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        
            <solid android:color="@color/danger_dark" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding android:left="20dp" android:right="20dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
        
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            
            <solid android:color="@color/danger" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding android:left="20dp" android:right="20dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
        
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Any ideas on how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how C# is related?

Comment: Xamarin.Android is a c# based framework with the same regular API.

Comment: Ok, maybe add it to the question & tags. So people who knows Xamarin can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether to call this a solution or a workaround but, I managed to solve the selector issue by using AndroidX's `AppCompatButton` instead of the traditional `Button`.

Just replaced this:

```xml
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
    android:text="Cancel"/>
```

By the following:

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
    android:text="Cancel"/>
```

I also changed the parent of my custom `Button` styles to `Widget.AppCompat.Button` instead of `@android:style/Widget.Button`.

Answer (score 1):

I had test your code in a Xamarin.Android project and a Xamarin.Forms project. In the android project, it didn't work any way even that I tried to add the button into an activity.xml. But in the android part of the forms project, it worked well. So this may be a special problem in xamarin.android. You can try to create a Forms project and do this in the android part of it. In addition, you can try to add an issue to the Xamarin.Android.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Liyun! I tried your suggestion regarding Xamarin.Forms applying the same steps in the Android project. But, unfortunately, got the same issue. Yet, it was already working for me in activities. Anyway, I  solved the issue and posted my solution in a separate answer.